# Охлотизация языка

Tags: общие-вопросы, недопустимая-метка, языковые-изменения

Что такое "охлотизация языка"? Каковы её последствия?

Comment: Также Вы вправе поинтересоваться о том, что такое "пауперизация языка" и каковы её последствия.

P.S. Между прочим, [заумное] словцо "пауперизация" не хуже, чем [заумное] словцо "охлотизация".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Охлос* по-гречески - народ, толпа, чернь (?), если я правильно помню. Охлократия ~ майданная власть, кто кого перекричит.
Охлотизация языка. Направленное снижение общей речевой грамотности в угоду повседневной мелкобуржуазной стихии : крупные дозы глупого смеха в масс-медиа, ежедневная погоня за удовольствиями ("вы достойны этого!"), неразборчивость в литературе и др. Превращение народа в стадо баранов, описанное Н.Носовым в "Незнайке на Луне", когда вместо речи из уст балбесов звучит жалобное блеяние.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо!

Comment: Отлично сказано, коротко и ёмко!

Answer (score 2):

Личность и толпа – вечное противостояние.

Толпа любит мелководье жизни с ее примитивно ясной прямотой (таинственные глубины её всегда пугают) и  не любит творчества, как процесс неведомый и непонятный. Человек из толпы всегда задает  вопросы: незнающий спрашивает, как ему стать образованным, бедный – как стать  богатым,  богатый – как стать счастливым. Им во всём нужно руководство и  правила. Такие люди  часто утверждают, что  живут ради других, но при этом  никогда не берут  на себя ответственность за свою собственную жизнь.

Сохранение индивидуальности в современном мире – задача все более сложная. Это определяется тем, что "коллективный разум непрерывно транслируется в сознание человека", и проблема собственной осознанности становится одной из самых важных. Примитивные понятия о жизни, свойственные толпе,  воздействуют и  на язык, и это негативное влияние также следует отметить.

Интересы толпы приходится учитывать государству. В 1918 году была принята орфографическая реформа, чтобы сделать грамотными широкие массы населения. В настоящее время идет перманентная реформа с целью сохранить хотя бы минимальный уровень грамотности. Для этого упрощаются и ужесточаются правила, уменьшаются возможности творческого письма, идет наступление на грамматику.  Ученик, едва осиливший грамотность, и художник слова  будут вынуждены писать по единому трафарету.

Личность всегда противостоит толпе. Таких людей единицы, но их энергетический потенциал несравненно выше.  Занимаясь творчеством и просветительством, создавая авторские школы, они борются за осмысленность и одухотворенность  нашего языка.

Comment: Похоже на школьное сочинение.

Comment: А тема раскрыта?

Comment: Спасибо, София!

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю о том, какими, на мой взгляд, будут последствия.

Положительными. Грамотность, способность ясно и целостно мыслить выживут в этом мутном потоке, но язык благодаря всем пертурбациям станет более живым и гибким, приобретёт бОльшую "пропускную способность".

Был железом - станет сталью (за счёт легирующих добавок).

Comment: Оптимизм помогает жить.
Спасибо!